# How to maintain Multiple Relation In tables Using Entity Framework Database first?

Tags: sql, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Entity Framework 5 (DB first).In my project I want to show data of two tables which don't have direct relation,
In following condition Table A is master Table. 
Table A and B are in relationship, B and C ,B and D are in relationship I want to show data from A,C and D . I don't know how should I maintain this relation in way that  help me to use ORM query in Razor view .So that I can Use only one main model of Table A to show relational tables data

[image]

Comment: It would help to see the class model, esp. to know if classes `C` and `D` have (or could have) collections of `B` and/or a reference to `A`. At the very least, please show how you would query only `A - C` for instance.

Answer (score 0):

I would normalize your schema, changing TableB with relations columns for relations with TableA, for TableC and TableD,

```
TABLE B:
ID | fk_A | fk_C | fk_D
B1    A1     C1    null
B2    A1     C2    null
B3    A2     C3    null
B4    A2     null  D1
B5    A3     null  D2
B6    A3     null  D3
```

I don't know the nature of the relationship, but if B meaning is only to join A with other columns you could also have B3 and B4 in a single record like: B7 A2 C3 D1